# How can I change connection string value residing in external config file (vb 2010)

Tags: configuration-files

Going through MSDN and various other posts on line, I understand that we can very well do away with the older method of ini files for writing and retrieving configuration details so as to be able to change database path/connection string. ([refer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms254494%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-4))

I am able to get the connection string data from an external file ("abcConnStr.config") and am able to read and write from / to the database tables as normally one would expect to.

However I am unable to crack the way I would be able to change / update the connection string value in the external file ("abcConnStr.config"). If I try to pass the value manually through a text box I get a message saying "Your step-into request resulted in an automatic step-over of a property or operator.....". When I click "Yes" the sub is completed without any further message or error. However when I open the config file ("abcConnStr.config"), I find that the value of the connection string has not changed.

May I request you to guide me as to how can I change the connection string parameter in the external config file ("abcConnStr.config").

Addl.info:

Here is the external config file that I am using:
File name:    **connStr.config**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NewConStr" 
    connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=&
    quot;D:\CATALOG\CATALOG_DB\CAT_DB.accdb&quot;"
    providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

I am using the following code line in appication.exe.config (app.config) file to access the database:

```
    <connectionStrings configSource="connStr.config" />
```

I am able to connect to the database if it resides in the file location as defined in the external config file. However, when I change the database location (put in another folder or change the name) as expected, the connection to the DB fails. At this point I am catching the exception and trying to call the sub to effect a change to the path value assigned to the "connectionString".

In the sub I want to call code/s to change the DB file path as selected by the user thru'"OpenFileDialog".

Kindly advise a possible way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution on [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/04/02/linq-to-xml-changing-connectionstring-in-app-config.aspx).

However, I will have to do away with external config file (for now, till I get a solution on it) and have ended up making changes to the application.exe.config file. It is working seamlessly.

I am using VB 2010 Pro.

Thanks.